# Resource recommendation for extreme value theory

Tags: references, extreme-value, extremal-dependence

I'm look to learn about extreme value theory, starting from univariate case and then moving onto the multivariate case.

I have tried the textbook by de Haan, but I'm constantly lost trying to read the proof of Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem in the first chapter. I have also tried Statistics of Extremes: Theory and Applications but I cannot get through the first few chapter either.

I have read EXTREMES AND RELATED PROPERTIES OF RANDOM SEQUENCES AND PROCESSES and found the section on on Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem understandable, but the book does not contain any section on multivariate analysis, and I'm not much interested in time series.

I have also tried D-Norms & Multivariate Extremes but found it hard to follow as it got to multivariate extreme part.

I'm looking for a comprehensive resource that covers multivariate extreme value theory. If anyone has any recommendation, I'd be grateful.

Comment: de Haan's book is classic. If you really are getting hiccups crossing the first chapter, then you need to cover the prerequisites first. It is a good question but you could specify your mathematical sophistication here in order to get a recommendation(s) that suits you.

Comment: @User1865345 I have covered Durett's book on probability upto and including martingale.